# Parse list of x,y coordinates and detect continious areas

Tags: python, math

I have a list of x, y coordinates

What I need to do is separate those into groups of continuous areas

[image]

All the x, y coordinates in a list will end up belonging to a particular group.

I currently have an simple algorithm, that just goes through each point and finds all the adjacent points (so points with coordinates of +-1 on x and +-1 on y)
However, it is much too slow when it comes to using large x,y lists.

PS Keep in mind that there could be holes in the middle of groups.

Comment: How large is your input data?

Comment: Could be more than 12 million points

Comment: If you search for "clustering", you'll find dozens of techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple method that you could use is [k-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). *k*-means partitions a list of observations into `k` clusters, where each point belongs to the cluster with the nearest mean. If you know that there are `k=2` groups of points, then this method should work very well, assuming your clusters of points are reasonably well separated (and even if they have holes). [SciPy has an implementation of k-means](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html) that should be easy to apply.

Here's an example of the type of analysis you can perform.

```
# import required modules
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2

# generate clouds of 2D normally distributed points
N = 6000000 # number of points in each cluster

# cloud 1: mean (0, 0)
mean1 = [0, 0]
cov1  = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
x1,y1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov1, N).T

# cloud 2: mean (5, 5)
mean2 = [5, 5]
cov2  = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
x2,y2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov2, N).T

# merge the clouds and arrange into data points
xs, ys = np.concatenate( (x1, x2) ), np.concatenate( (y1, y2) )
points = np.array([xs, ys]).T

# cluster the points using k-means
centroids, clusters = kmeans2(points, k=2)
```

Running this on my 2012 MBA with 12 million data points is pretty fast:

```
>>> time python test.py

real    0m20.957s
user    0m18.128s
sys     0m2.732s
```

It is also 100% accurate (not surprising given that the point clouds don't overlap at all). Here's some quick code for computing the accuracy of the cluster assignments. The only tricky part is I first use Euclidean distance to identify which cluster's centroid matches up with the mean of the original data cloud.

```
# determine which centroid belongs to which cluster
# using Euclidean distance
dist1 = np.linalg.norm(centroids[0]-mean1)
dist2 = np.linalg.norm(centroids[1]-mean1)
if dist1 <= dist2:
    FIRST, SECOND = 0, 1
else:
    FIRST, SECOND = 1, 0

# compute accuracy by iterating through all 2N points
# note: first N points are from cloud1, second N points are from cloud2
correct = 0
for i in range(len(clusters)):
    if clusters[i] == FIRST and i < N:
        correct += 1    
    elif clusters[i] == SECOND and i >= N:
        correct += 1

# output accuracy
print 'Accuracy: %.2f' % (correct*100./len(clusters))
```

Comment: I never know how many bounded clusters there will be. could I still use this method?

Comment: Yes, you will just have to test different values of `k`.

Comment: This is a statistical method, it's sometimes going to have errors - if some group of pixels is disconnected from another group by a single missing pixel, I don't think it's always going to go right. Instead scipy.ndimage.label does exactly what he asks for.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: it is a statistical approach and you can't guarantee performance across all datasets. But "if a pixel is away from a group by a single pixel it's going to (sic) wrong" is incorrect. As long as that pixel is closer to one group than the other, it will be assigned correctly (assuming the method converges).

Comment: Well what I meant was -- we don't know his data nor his actual problem, but he says he's looking for a way to divide into groups based on connectivity. So I think it's a shame we assume the groups are well separated (and what about groups inside the holes in other groups?) because the problem doesn't mention that. But I don't know why I'm arguing this, have a nice day :-)

Comment: I agree with you that since we don't know the OP's data, it is important to state our assumptions, which I tried to do in my answer. Your solution is nice and well-suited as well. I didn't want to argue, just wanted to get on the same page :)

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called finding *connected components* in image processing. You have a binary image in which all the (x, y) pixels that are in your list are 1, and pixels that aren't are 0.

You can use numpy/scipy to turn your data into a 2D binary image, and then call ndimage.label to find the connected components.

Suppose all x and y are >= 0, you know max_x and max_y, and the resulting image fits into memory, then something like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

image = np.zeros(max_x, max_y)
for x, y in huge_list_of_xy_points:
    image[x, y] = 1

labelled = ndimage.label(image)
```

Should give you an array in which all pixels in group 1 have value 1, all pixels in groups 2 have value 2, et cetera. Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can identify the problem with a corresponding graph `G(V, E)`:

Points are vertices and there is an edge `e` between point `A` and point `B` if and only if `A` is "close" to `B`, where you can define "close" on your own.

Since each point belongs to exactly one group, groups form disjoint sets and you can use a simple [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to assign points to groups. In graph theory the underlying problem is called [Connected Components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29).

The complexity of DFS is linear i.e. `O(V + E)`.